# Error:InvalidPipeArgument: '2018-05-28 15:17:47' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Tags: angular

Safari Report errors:

```
Error:InvalidPipeArgument: '2018-05-28 15:17:47' for pipe 'DatePipe'
Safari 11.0.3(13604.5.6)
```

Chrome Run perfectly,

Comment: you need to share your code.

Comment: <td>{{data.CreateDate|date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>

Comment: I believe IE will also fail with that Date format as well. If you replace the space with a `T` character, (i.e. `2018-05-28T15:17:47`) then it should parse it fine

Comment: Add more details to your question

Comment: Annotated this section of the code will not be wrong

Comment: That is not an ISO date format, and that's what the date pipe support. So just fix your code to use the ISO format. https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: @JBNizet，yes,string,Do I need a conversion type

Comment: @邱杰克 I have no idea of what you mean by that. The DatePipe accepts strings, but not **any** string. The string has to be a valid ISO datetime string. So fix your code to use that, rather than your non-ISO format.